# Increase number of "Recent places" in Preview.app NSNavPanel drop-down

Tags: finder, preview

I frequently use the quick-save drop-down panel of Preview.app, and I want to increase the number of "Recent places" from the default 5.  I typically use it to re-file downloaded documents into the correct folder on my computer.  I'm probably not using the right name for it, so here's a screenshot:

[image: Quick-save drop-down pane in Preview.app]

The bit I often use is the "Recent places" section.  I'd absolutely love it if I could have 10 or more places there, so that I didn't have to keep using "Other..." and poking around with an awkward NSNav pane.

I've tried a few approaches.

1. System Preferences > General > Recent Items drop down menu.  Set to 30.  This only seems to affect the top-left main Apple menu's recent items, so no luck there.
2. More involved: using the `defaults` command I found on [this random forum](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090106183327762):

   `defaults write .GlobalPreferences NSNavRecentPlacesLimit -int 20`

   This seems to affect the number of recent places shown when you use the File > Save As... dialog in Preview.app, but that's unfortunately not what I'm after.

So finally, my question is:

Is there a setting I can change which is specific to Preview.app?  Or is this something related to NSNavPanels?  How can I find out?  Perhaps there is a way to get a log of what values an app is trying to access from the `defaults` store?  Alternatively, where can I find documentation about NSNav or NSNavPanel, so learn what values they use?